# As the seconds add up I get further away

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> You and I, we run the same race
>
> Though I'm always one step behind
>
> I might try to tempt you to slow your pace
>
> But keep your eyes forward, it's fine.
>
> That said, don't ignore me completely
>
> My actions should serve as a guide
>
> Try your best to do better than me,
>
> But if not, well... at least you tried

---

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be

> Yesterday

You and I, we run the same race
Though I'm always one step behind

> Yesterday is one day (step) behind in time.

I might try to tempt you to slow your pace
But keep your eyes forward, it's fine.

> By focusing on yesterday, you can get caught up in nostalgia and regret. One should really look to tomorrow.

That said, don't ignore me completely
My actions should serve as a guide

> It is important to learn from what happened yesterday.

Try your best to do better than me,
But if not, well... at least you tried

> A person should always try to grow from the day before.

Title

> As time moves on, yesterday becomes further away.

Comment: Very close, but the past is a broad term. It can be a single step behind you, or miles behind

Comment: @Cubemaster I've edited my answer with your comment in mind.

Comment: That was awfully fast... I must be losing my edge

Comment: @Cubemaster does that make you a spheremaster?

Comment: @Brandon_J Hey now, I'm not that far gone.